# Upgrading to AngularFire 5.0

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm using ionic 3 with firebase.

Until now I use angularfire 4.0 and the following code gave me an observable for the data from firebase:

```
  obsToData: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public shared: SharedProvider, 
              public DB: AngularFireDatabase) {

              this.obsToData = DB.object('/myData');
  }
```

now, according to [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md) page `FirebaseObjectObservable` removed and I need to use `AngularFireObject` instead, how can I get the data?

I did the following change:

```
obsToData: AngularFireObject<any>;

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public shared: SharedProvider,
              public DB: AngularFireDatabase) {

              this.obsToData = DB.object('/myData');
  }
```

but I don't find the way how to get an observable from this new object to my data from firebase.

Does someone succeed to use angularfire 5.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use [`valueChanges()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md#create-an-object-binding) to get the Observable from the AngularFireDatabase Object reference.

```
obsRef: AngularFireObject<any>;
obsToData: Observable<any>;

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public shared: SharedProvider,
              public DB: AngularFireDatabase) {

              this.obsRef = DB.object('/myData');//reference
              this.obsToData = this.obsRef.valueChanges();//Observable
  }
```

**EDIT** to get data and save it,subscribe like any observable

```
  this.obsToData.subscribe(data=>{
       console.log(data);
  },error=>{
       console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: The problem is that FirebaseObjectObservable in angularfire 4 was imported from angularfire2/database, but in angularfire 5 it seems it is not defined there so it is not compiled now.

Do you know from where it should be imported now?

Comment: Change the type to `Observable<any>`

Comment: Now it is compiling successfully, but I don't get my data in obsToData. Is it should be in this variable?

Comment: You need to subscribe to it.. depends on how you are accessing . Console log in subscribe.

Comment: I found the way with subscribe. Thank you very much

Comment: @rafraph can you post your code with the subscribe please? i can get the data to show using the async pipe in HTML, but unsure how to store the data into an array or console.log it. thanks

Comment: @Reza check updated answer.. you just use the observable